# Docker Container restart after VM reboot

Tags: docker

we have deployed docker container and the restart policy is `--restart unless-stopped`. This will start the container after VM reboot. The docker service is also enabled to start the service after reboot.

The problem is whenever reboot happen, the list of containers and images all are gone. Solution for this is to restart the docker service. so after this container is coming up.

so question is why do we need to restart the docker service even after it is enabled to start after reboot?

appreciate help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the truly internals of Docker Engine, but I make my assumptions:

On Virtual Machine (or native host) restart, the docker engine is stopped, so the containers receive a "stop" signal too (in background a `systemctl stop docker` will be performed)

What you are doing with `systemctl restart docker` (or similar command) is sending a "restart" signal to the docker engine, not a "stop" one.

You should use `--restart always` if you want to be sure that the containers are restarted automatically when the VM is freshly started/restarted.

Comment: I've tried with ```--restart always``` still having same issue.

Comment: The issue has been resolved, we have a local ```root FS partition``` and that is our docker ```data-root```. Docker service start is happening before the mount. That's the root cause for me.